# Saving and re-using value of a footnote counter twice - how?

Tags: footnotes, counters

I am trying to put the same footnote on to two different places - saving and re-using the footnote counter. Here is what I want to do (part of a larger doc - a paper out of my dissertation):

```
%Start LateX snippet%

$\Delta$ Age\footnote{\FNTabAge}        
\newcounter{savetmp01} \setcounter{savetmp01}{\value{mpfootnote}} %Save "a"%

Grade\footnote{\FNTabGrade}
\newcounter{savetmp02} \setcounter{savetmp02}{\arabic{mpfootnote}} %Save "b"%

Grade\footnotemark[\arabic{savetmp02}] x Non-English %Reuse "b" - works%

$\Delta$ Age\footnotemark[\arabic{savetmp01}] x Non-English %Reuse "a" - does not work. Instead it shows "b"%
```

I want to save the footnote counter first when defining `$Delta$ Age`, and then again when explaining Grade.

The first re-use works perfectly well (both show the same footnotemark "b"), but the second re-use does not work - I am getting "b" again, instead of "a" as I want it.

Any ideas? Already tried using `\thesavetmp01` or `\value{savetmp01}`, but no luck.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Tip: You can mark code by selecting it and hitting Ctrl + K (or clicking the button marked `{}` above the text field). Also, I removed the thanks.  Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: I found the FAQ at <https://texfaq.org/FAQ-repfootnote> to be helpful. It explains the use of footnotemark in simpler cases and the use of labelling in more complicated cases. It also presents commands provided in some other packages.

Answer (score 13):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but the `savefnmark` package seems to do what you need:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=6cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{savefnmark}

\begin{document}

Some text\footnote{footnote 1 in text} some more text\footnote{footnote 2 in text}\saveFN\sft\  and now more text and the same footnote counter that was saved\useFN\sft\ and perhaps more text and we finally use the counter one more time\useFN\sft.

\end{document}
```

[image]